# what is the measurement when calculate distance between 2 points latitude-longitude in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, latitude-longitude

I'm calculating distance between 2 points latitude-longitude in Google BigQuery using `ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(start_lat,start_lng),ST_GEOGPOINT(end_lat,end_lng))` and what is the measurements( m/km/miles?) for the calculated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance):

`ST_DISTANCE` function:

> Returns the shortest distance in **meters** between two non-empty
> GEOGRAPHYs.

Answer (score 1):

As Alvaro replied, it is meters.

I want to also warn about a possible mistake in the question: [`ST_GEOGPOINT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogpoint) takes longitude as first argument, latitude as second. So to get correct results you need

```
ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(start_lng, start_lat),
            ST_GEOGPOINT(end_lng, end_lat))
```